# Tkinter : hide shell console when run a program

Tags: tkinter, console, hide

I would like to hide the shell window when I run my program.
I tried many solutions, as rename my file using the "pyw" extension, or use the command as following :

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
```

But these 2 solutions don't work.
I would like to avoid to need to install win32gui and others extern modules (even if apparently some solutions using them are possible).

Thank for the help !!!!!

Comment: Just as a note, if you use a different IDE, or convert the file to an EXE file, you can have the program run without showing the console or shell window.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try !!!!

Comment: But if there is a solution, just to reduce this console window in the title bar, I am still interested